# Saving a text file in the specified location using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, file

I want to be able to create a text file and save it in a particular location using HTML and Javascript. I want to download the file into the location which I specify in the code, without changing the browsers settings. I want to be able to do this on Node JS.

Comment: Please ask a specific question about your code, and post your code.

Comment: what you're asking for is not possible, nor allowed by browsers because that's a safety violation. For example, if you can change the directory location you can also change the name, let's say you create a file called loveletter.txt, now you could save it as /etc/hosts or C:/windows/system32/etc/hosts or something like that which contains rogue hosts; now when your victim tries to go to a site (say google.com) they can endup where you pointed them and bob's your uncle. Thus the limitations :)

Comment: Why do people ask this question every day. It's been asked and answered so many times...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: Create and save file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file)

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, JavaScript isn't allowed to force a download at all, let alone to a specific location. It's not possible to do what you're asking.

Comment: That is not totally true. You **can** create and download files using JavaScript. You just can't force where it downloads to.

Comment: @spencer.sm You can't *force* a download at all. All you can do is make the browser *offer* a download.

Comment: Responding to your comment before you edited it, I did try it and I got a download prompt. If you use Chrome and have "Ask where to save each file before downloading" turned off, then you can force a download there, but that's the exception rather than the rule.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. See this article for more: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/